# Python [Errno 10054] only when the query is in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, urllib2

I am using python 2.7 to retrieve some data from a reporting api.

The api is fairly simple (it is Rakuten linkshare's reporting api):
- basically, you query a URL with your user token and date range and it returns a CSV with the data requested.

To do that I am using the read_csv function from pandas:

```
url = 'https://ran-reporting.rakutenmarketing.com/en/reports/api_report_xxxx/filters?start_date='+start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'\
&end_date='+end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'&include_summary=N&network=3&tz=GMT&date_type=transaction&\
token=XXX'

lkshare_data = pd.read_csv(url, thousands=',')
```

So far so good. My problem occurs when I am trying to wrap this into a function:
I keep on getting `"httplib.BadStatusLine: ''" or "socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"`
depending on the different solutions I tried.

After searching for solutions on the web for a (very) long time I find myself stuck.

Any help would be extremly appreciated!

Aymeric.

**Update 1** - This is the code in question:

`def rev_aff_linkshare(start_date, end_date):
    """This function should return the report as a pandas dataframe"""

## The url of the API, when you call it, it returns a csv-like file with the data.

```
url = 'https://ran-reporting.rakutenmarketing.com/en/reports/api_report/filters?start_date='+start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'\
&end_date='+end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+'&include_summary=N&network=3&tz=GMT&date_type=transaction&\
token=XXXXXX'
```

## the conversion into a pandas DataFrame

```
lkshare = pd.read_csv(url, thousands=',')
return lkshare`
```

This function through the error "socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

I have tried many different solution but find myself completely stuck at the moment

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

A.

Comment: You should include the problematic code as well.

Comment: Sure will update the post.